# Awk that I am stuck on

Tags: shell, awk

I have a project I am working on for work. The script I am building initially takes two arguments: one is an unique Identifier and the other is for a log file (both strings). Now I have the first part of it done which is parsing for the unique Identifier. But the second part, is parsing for a specific piece of string which is a randomly generated string of numbers and letters.

I am using a `awk` statement to get this random string and I have verified that my expression is correct in Rubular. But when I attempt to test the code with more, nothing prints out. Here is what I typed in the command line:

```
awk '/\s=\s[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/ {print }' ~/jlog/server.log | more
```

Here is what I have in my script:

```
for j in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do awk '/'"$1"'/\s=\s[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/ {print}'
```

And here a piece of the log I am parsing through:

```
2014-06-17 15:34:52,406 INFO  [random.random.xxx.message.Random] Processed instance (1.2.840.113619.2.284.3.2013961368.890.1402186239.15
5/1.2.840.113619.2.80.1944071037.22604.1402323463.136) from random@email.com to Random_AE.  AssociationID = 9eddb1b0-368e-4fb9-a684-44cc14be389c
```

I am looking specifically for the random code after the Association ID. Is there any suggestions on how to display the results? I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Please try `awk '$3=="INFO" && $(NF-2)=="AssociationID" && $(NF-1)=="=" { print $NF }' ~/jlog/server.log`. You can directly use `awk` on your logfile without needing `for` and `cat`.

Comment: Excellent!! Can you post that as your answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
awk '$3=="INFO" && $(NF-2)=="AssociationID" && $(NF-1)=="=" { print $NF }' ~/jlog/server.log
```

By passing the logfile's name directly to `awk` you can avoid using `for` and `cat` too.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Only problem is it is giving me the wrong association ID. Here is the full line of code i have for it: `for j in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do awk '$3=="INFO" && $(NF-2)=="AssociationID" && $(NF-1)=="=" { print $NF;exit}' ~/jlog/"$2"`

Comment: Nevermind, found the problem. Thanks!! I was missing a grep statement